# Subdivide/ Decompose a simplex into "congruent" simplices

Tags: geometry

So my question is about subdividing/decomposing a simplex into simpleces that are shrunken versions of the original simplex.

For example for both the regular simplex and the simplex with a right angle in 2D (so basically equilateral triangle and isosceles triangle with a right angle) this works fine.

However, for 3D this seems not to work for the simplex with the right angle and I am not sure for the regular simplex due to the octahedron in the middle.

Can someone either confirm that this does not work in 3D or give a valid solution?
Also, does it work in general for either of the two simplices or does it not work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to the [Dehn invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant).
If $T$ is a tetrahedron then a congruent tetrahedron $T'$
of half its side lengths satisfies $D(T)=2D(T')$ where $D$
denotes Dehn invariant. But for eight copies of $T'$ to cover
$T$ we need $D(T)=8D(T')$ and so $6D(T')=0$ (which implies
$6D(T)=0$). But in the group of Dehn invariants, $D(T)$ is
a non-torsion element, so this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! That "solves" kind of my problem, then I have to look for another, maybe barycentric, subdivision.
Short side question: Does the Dehn Variant also prevent me from subdividing the regular tetrahedron with pairwise congruent tetrahedra that have a right angle?